# Linear forms and the second Voronoi decomposition

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-geometry, abelian-varieties, quadratic-forms, total-unimodularity

This is not my area of expertise, so forgive me if the question is a bit naive. Given a collection of vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_d$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with $d\geq n$), there is a corresponding set of quadratic forms given by $v_i\cdot v_i^t$. One can show these quadratic forms span a cone of the 2nd-Voronoi decomposition exactly when the matrix whose columns are given by the $v_i$'s is totally unimodular (that is, every $n\times n$ minor is either 0 or $\pm 1$).

I wonder what is known when the matrix is not totally unimodular. In that case, we can still subdivide it into subcones of 2nd-Voronoi cones. Do the minors tell us anything about this union? For instance, if the minors are $\pm 2,\pm 1,0$, do we get a bound on the number of 2nd Voronoi cones?